# DFS after remove some edge

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, vertex, edge-list

I have a graph with one source vertex and a list of the edges, where in each iteration one edge from the list is going to be removed from the graph.

For each vertex i have to print the number of iterations after it lost its connection to the source vertex- there will be no path between the vertex and the source.

My idea is to run DFS algorithm from the source vertex in each iteration and increment the value of the vertexes, which have the connection with the source vertex- there is a path between the vertex and the source vertex.

I'm sure there is a better idea than run the dfs algorithm from the source vertex in each iteration. But I don't know how to resolve the problem in better, faster way.

Comment: So, your actual question is "what other, more efficient algorithms than one described above can I use to solve the problem"?

Comment: Important detail is, do you know which edge, between which verexes, is removed? If not, you'd have to search to find it, so I doubt there's anything better than you describe... If yes, then there's potential I think.

Comment: Yes i know exactly which edge is removed. I have the list of the edges to remove and start removing from the 1st position on the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the whole edge list in advance, you can process it backwards, connecting the graph instead of disconnecting it.

In pseudo-code:

```
GIVEN:
edges = list of edges
outputMap = new empty map from vertex to iteration number
S = source vertex

//first remove all the edges in the list
for (int i=0;i<edges.size();i++) {
   removeEdge(edges[i]);
}

//find vertices that are never disconnected
//use DFS or BFS
foreach vertex reachable from S
{
   outputMap[vertex] = -1;
}

//walk through the edges backward, reconnecting
//the graph
for (int i=edges.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    Vertex v1 = edges[i].v1;
    Vertex v2 = edges[i].v2;
    Vertex newlyConnected = null;

    //this is for an undirected graph
    //for a directed graph, you only test one way
    //is a new vertex being connected to the source?
    if (outputMap.containsKey(v1) && !outputMap.containsKey(v2))
        newlyConnected = v2;
    else if (outputMap.containsKey(v2) && !outputMap.containsKey(v1))
        newlyConnected = v1;

    if (newlyConnected != null)
    {
        //BFS or DFS again
        foreach vertex reachable from newlyConnected
        {
            //It's easy to calculate the desired remove iteration number
            //from our add iteration number
            outputMap[vertex] = edges.size()-i;
        }
    }
    addEdge(v1,v2);
}

//generate output
foreach entry in outputMap
{
    if (entry.value >=0)
    {
       print("vertex "+entry.key+" disconnects in iteration "+entry.value);
    }
}
```

This algorithm achieves linear time, since each vertex is only involved in a single BFS or DFS, before it gets connected to the source.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to reverse time, so that we're thinking about adding edges one by one and determining when connectivity to the source is achieved. Your idea of performing a traversal after each step is a good one. To get the total cost down to linear, you need the following optimization and an amortized analysis. The optimization is that you save the set of visited vertices from traversal to traversal and treat the set as one "supervertex", deleting intra-set edges as they are traversed. The cost of each traversal is proportional to the number of edges thus deleted, hence the amortized linear running time.